# Change a node to be a comment node

Tags: pugixml

I have a reference to an `xml_node`. Is there a way to change it to be a comment type node (`node_comment`)? Essentially to comment the node out.

Answer (score 1):

For converting an element into a comment, you'd want to use something along these lines:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
node.print(oss, "", pugi::format_raw);

auto comment = node.parent().insert_child_before(pugi::node_comment, node);
comment.set_value(oss.str().c_str());

node.parent().remove_child(node);
```